# Is "那些你很冒險的夢" a common expression or just a song title?

Tags: translation, grammar

Also is there a simple translation of it into English? As far as I can tell it says "those you very adventurous dreams", but this doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: this totally not fits grammar。

Answer (score 5):

It's a song title for singer JJ and it's better translation for

> Those Adventurous Dreams of Yours

because it's written for the writer's girlfreind , and he want to complete the dreams with the girl.

---

ps. there's no one will say `那些你很冒險的夢` in real life.

Answer (score 2):

- 那些 = Those
- 你很冒險的 = of you being very adventurous
- 夢 = dreams

> [那些][你很冒險的][夢] = [Those] [dreams][of you being very adventurous]
>
> Those dreams are not adventurous, you are!

"你很冒險" means "you are adventurous"

"的" is an adjective suffix that turns the regular sentence "你很冒險" into an adjective phrase (你很冒險的) to modify "夢".

*Q: "Dreams?" "What dreams?"*

*A: "the dreams of you being adventurous"*

It is not a common expression, but it is not totally senseless. It can be phrased more clearly though.

For example:

"**那些你在中夢很冒險的夢** "(those dreams that you are very adventurous in them)

Edit:

"你那些很冒險的夢" mean the dream is adventurous. Not you. "those adventurous dreams of yours” should be "你那些冒險夢" (those adventure dreams of yours). Adventure here would be a adjectival noun.

*Q: "Dreams?" "What dreams?"*

*A: "The adventure dreams"*

Comment: I totally understand your translation. But why could it not (also) mean “those adventurous dreams of yours”, i.e. 那些 + 你 + omitted 的 + 很冒險的夢? Or should it be 你的那些很冒險的夢 then? Is this translation wrong or is it just a question of how you read it?

Comment: "你那些很冒險的夢" mean the dream is adventurous. Not you.  "those adventurous dreams of yours”  should be "你那些冒險夢" (those adventure dreams of yours) adventure here would be a adjectival noun

Comment: What sentence is that: "那些你在中夢很冒險的夢 "?

Comment: I think parsing it as 那些/你/很冒险的梦 is just as reasonable as 那些/你很冒险的/梦, which give slightly different meanings. The main point is that this is not standard expression, so it doesn't have standard interpretation either.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pop song title and so some expressive artistic licence could be allowed.

It is not the grammar we are hot under the collar about here, but to a native speaker it sounds "fractured, broken, affected", clumsy even, like someone pointed out you don't ordinarily speak like that in real life, just as in English you don't in ordinary conversation say to someone who is "under the weather", OMG, your countenance is a whiter shade of pale.